# background image as link using css/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div containing the background image but i want to make that image as clickable and pointed to somewhere site. Is it possible to do this in css or jquery 
**HTML**:

```
<div id="logincontainer">
</div>
```

**css**  :

```
  #loginContainer {
        -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
            -moz-border-left-colors: none;
            -moz-border-right-colors: none;
            -moz-border-top-colors: none;
            background: url("http://s3.buysellads.com/1237708/176570-1371740695.gif") 
            no-repeat scroll center center #FF660D;  /*for example */
            border-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-image: none;
            border-right: medium solid #FFFFFF;
            border-style: none solid solid;
            border-width: medium;
            left: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            position: fixed;
            min-height:200px;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            vertical-align: super;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 9999999;
        }
```

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/16/

I am not sure is there is a way to make the background image as clickable which is pointed in div?
Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: No, not without adding a `<a>` or using JavaScript and the click event.

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct solution, but it will work, have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/a39Va/17/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
<a href="whereYouWantToGo"><div id="loginContainer'></div></a>
```

Or you can do that as well via JavaScript and jQuery

```
$('#loginContainer').click(function(e) { <Whatever you want to do here> });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using an anchor ?

```
<a href="link" id="logincontainer">
</a>
```

i updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/18/)

otherwise :

- you can click on any element to behave like a link with jQuery.
- you can surround your `<div>` in an anchor if you use the html5 `<!DOCTYPE>` ( *Otherwise invalid* )

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the `z-index` of the background element, and as others have said, add an anchor or a javascript action. Also, I added some sample of the rest of the content on the page. You need to see how the two interact with each other.

Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/19/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="loginContainer">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Something</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loginContainer {
    background: url("http://s3.buysellads.com/1237708/176570-1371740695.gif") 
    no-repeat center #FF660D;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
#loginContainer a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I don't _like_ these sort of interactions. It is always frustrating to me when a web site makes the entire background, or a huge area of the page, clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/nkb85/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="logincontainer" data-link="http://google.com"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $('#logincontainer').hover(function() {

    var divLink = $(this).attr('data-link');

    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + divLink + '"></a>');

  });

});
```